# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'

Tags: android

While running the app this error is coming More than one file was found with OS independent path '**META-INF/rxjava.properties**' . How to remove duplicate file from android studio ?

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem. The way I fixed it is adding the packagingOptions in app gradle as described in Duplicated file rxjava.properties

```
android {
      defaultConfig {
      }
      buildTypes {
      }
      packagingOptions{
      exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
      }
}
```